# Hibernate não está criando as tabelas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, tomcat

Sou novo no assunto Hibernate, pelo pouco que já aprendi, eu acredito que fiz tudo certo, ou seja, baixei as dependências, anotei as classes, etc. Abaixo segue minha classe exemplo:

```
package br.com.evolutionary.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Pokemon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Agora segue meu arquivo persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="evolutionary"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evolutionary" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Meu arquivo pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>evolutionary</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Seguinte, ao iniciar o tomcat, as entidades não são criadas, não vejo log do hibernate. Então minhas perguntas são:
Precisa configurar algo no tomcat?
O hibernate é iniciado de outra maneira?
Alguém me ajude por favor?

**Obs: Os arquivos acima foram alterados baseados nas respostas já obtidas e por perguntas.**

Comment: Você fez todas as anotações corretamente nas classes que serão persistidas? ( Entity, Id, Collumn, etc.. )

Comment: Poste o Log que ele gera, senão fica dificil te ajudar.

Comment: @SérgioMucciaccia vou editar minha pergunta e adicionar o código.

Comment: @Geferson vou editar a pergunta e adicionar a saída.

Comment: O mapeamento da classe está correto. o arquivo de persistência, deixe como update ao invés de create. o Create apaga o banco toda vez que executar e cria novamente. o update apenas atualiza, comenta essa tag generateDdl, o log acredito que tenha mais coisas, você postou o que está na aba do log do tomcat?

Comment: @Douglas Seu problema foi resolvido?

Comment: @Matheus em parte sim. Vou fazer mais uns ajustes ainda.

Comment: @Douglas, Já tenteou adicionar suas entidades em tags `<class></class>`.?

Comment: Acabei de passar pelo mesmo problema. Uma possível solução proposta encontra-se no repositório git: https://github.com/plinio352/WebHibernate.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema pode ser solucionado quando fiz configurações dentro do wildfly ficando assim:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pokemax" pool-name="pokemax" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pokemax?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>pokemax</user-name>
                        <password>pokemax</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

Answer (score 4):

Há dois problemas no seu XML.

**1- Está faltando a propriedade *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto*, onde está sendo apresentada comentada.**

**2- Está faltando as classes mapeadas no Xml.**

Adicione tais tag no seu Xml para resolver o problema.

```
<!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

<!-- entidade mapeada -->
<class>br.com.sales.model.Empresa</class>
```

> Exemplo de XML:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="model" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

   <!-- entidade mapeada -->
   <class>br.com.sales.model.Empresa</class>
   <class>br.com.sales.model.Cliente</class>
   <class>br.com.sales.model.ProdutosVO</class>
   <class>br.com.sales.model.Logger</class>

  <properties>
  <!-- dados da conexao -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="connect123" />

   <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

  <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

No controller, apenas precisa apontar para o Xml:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("model");
```

Comment: Meu hibernate detecta automaticamente as tabelas anotadas. Ainda não funciona :/

Comment: @Douglas Qual o banco?

Comment: Mysql. @Matheus

Comment: @Douglas Tentou utilizar o XML de exemplo?

Comment: @Douglas Se eu não estiver enganado, você está usando as libs erradas na hora de criar a conexão. No seu caso, está utilizando  javax.persistence, já no meu hibernate.connection.

Comment: não usei seu xml todo não, apenas conferi referente ao meu. Como eu corrijo a questão das libs?

Comment: @Apenas altere as referências javax.persistence.jdbc para hibernate.connection como mostra no exemplo. Provavelmente as libs do hibernate você já tem no classpath. (Hibernate3 , Hibernate-JPA-2 ).

Comment: Já alterei e nada.

Comment: Adicionei o meu pom.xml para mais esclarecimento porque até agora nada.

Comment: Outro ponto é: Qual o momento exato do hibernate criar as tabelas? Ao subir o servidor de aplicação?

Comment: @Douglas Não, ele só irá criar as tabelas quando a aplicação tentar inserir um dado no banco ou realizar um select da classe mapeada.

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso eclipselink e após a persistence-unit tenho que declara as classes que são Entity. Segue abaixo exemplo:

```
  <persistence-unit name="clientes" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <class>JPA.ClientePOJO</class>
       <class>JPA.EmprestimoPOJO</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,
adicione a seguinte propriedade no seu persistence.xml:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

com a opção update ele sempre vai manter o banco atualizado toda vez que você rodar a aplicação.

segue um exemplo do meu persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Ramon"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso o banco ainda não foi criado, o update server para bancos já criados, não?

Comment: @Douglas Sim, o banco tem de estar criado.

Comment: @Matheus para ficar claro, o banco já está criado, o hibernate não está criando as tabelas, etc. Este é o meu problema.

Comment: @Douglas  A resposta do amorim resolve seu problema.

Comment: Ainda não consigo @Matheus, sabe se o hibernate gera log?

Answer (score 1):

Retire o comentário da linha
property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"

Answer (score 1):

Para suas entidade serem detectadas automaticamente o persistence.xml precisa estar no mesmo classpath que as classes anotadas com o @Entity, você também deve definir como falso o elemento:

```
<persistence-unit name="evolutionary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

E depois definir a propriedade:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
```